# Select/Decelect Row in DataGridView

Tags: c#, database, winforms, select, datagridview

I'm trying to insert/update Data into a `DataGridView` but ran into a small Problem.

In the `DataGridView`are certain cells with a date and a starting time (datetime). 
Now what i'm trying to do is when a button is pressed the current date should be searched for, the row selected, then the start Time should be read and with the current time a TimeSpan should be calculated.

Right now i'm just trying to get the row selected to take out the data of the starttime cell.

```
var Today = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

        dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Clear();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[0].Value.Equals(Today))
            {
                row.Selected = true;
            }
        }
```

But this gives me an error that the Listing is read only...i'm not really sure what i did wrong here?

So i'd appreaciate it if someone could help me with this or give me a tip on how to solve this Problem.

Thanks in advance to everyone. :)

Comment: Which line gives you an error?

Comment: @Ivan Stoev thanks for commenting. The lines "dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Clear();" and "if (row.Cells[0].Value.Equals(Today))" gives an error.

Comment: @scitch The error is not in the if statement, it is because calling dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Clear();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you try to clear selection in your `DataGridView` using `dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Clear();` you will receive an exception: `Operation not supported. Collection is read-only.`

To clear selection, you can use [`ClearSelection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.clearselection?WT.mc_id=5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method:

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
```

Comment: thank you very much! 
Now i only get the error that the object reference was not appointed to a object instance.... :-/

Comment: You should check what is null, using a breakpoint. Maybe your `row.Cells[0]` is null for some rows, Where do you receive the error?

Comment: I get the error at the "if (row.Cells[0].Value.Equals(Today))
" Statement.
The values i get by using a breakpoint are both there though. 
16.11.2015 for row.Cells[0].Value and 16.11.2015 for Today...

Comment: So it seems the problem is what I said, some rows, have null value in first cell and you need a null checking. For example as first line of `foreach`, you can write `if(row.Cells[0].Value==null) continue;

Comment: Oh wow thank you very much....i don't think i would've solved this on my own. :-)

Comment: I upvoted the answer. Do you know why the collection is read-only? I made the datagridview not as read only, so I'm wondering why the collection would be..

Comment: @sksallaj It's [SelectedRows](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection.cs.html) collection which is read-only and it's implemented this way.